# Get the sheet name in a column when workbook contain about 50 worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook contain about 50 worksheets (sheet 1, sheet 2, sheet 3,........, sheet 50). I want to get the sheet name as a column infront of my data in each sheet. I used following code for that.

```
Sub tgr1()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim wsDest As Worksheet

    Set wsDest = Sheets("Sheet1")

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
        If ws.Name <> wsDest.Name Then
            ws.Range("A:A").Insert Shift:=xlToRight
            'Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
            ws.Range("A12").FormulaR1C1 = _
            "=IF(RC[1]>0,MID(CELL(""filename"",R[-11]C[1]),FIND(""]"",CELL(""filename"",R[-11]C[1]))+1,255),"""")"
            ws.Range("A12").Copy
            ws.Range("A13:A500").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas
            ws.Range("A12:A500").Copy
            ws.Range("A12:A500").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        End If
        ActiveWorkbook.Save
    Next ws
```

But this code isn't working for all the sheets i have. it applies to random sheets. What should i do to make it apply for all the sheets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1.** Change `ActiveWorkbook` to `ThisWorkbook`

**2.** To get the worksheet name all you need is `ws.Range("A12").Value = Ws.Name`

**3.** No point saving the workbook each time the loop runs. Do it outside the loop.

Is this what you are trying?

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim wsDest As Worksheet

    Set wsDest = Sheets("Sheet1")

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        If ws.Name <> wsDest.Name Then
            ws.Columns(1).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
            ws.Range("A12:A500").Value = ws.Name
        End If
    Next ws
    
    ThisWorkbook.Save
    DoEvents
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Now it applies to all the sheets(Solved the issue i had with random sheets). But now sheet name only appears in A12 cell. I need to repeat it for each and every rows which contain data in the sheet. (sheets contain different number of rows, eg-50,60,..,etc )

Comment: All the data i have is in 12th row and below

Comment: You need to refresh the page. I had already made that edit ;)

Comment: BTW if there are going to be different number of rows then you might want to find the last row as shown [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-excel-with-vba/11169920#11169920) and then do `ws.Range("A12:A" & LastRow).Value = ws.Name`